# Android - Contact list names numbers array

Tags: java, android

**How can I simply get all contact names only in an array and all numbers in another array with no listviews or any layouts just progrmatically**

Comment: I'm not sure what this means. Please show your code and provide more detail.

Comment: I'm still working on one. I'll explain more, I am trying to fully understand and learn the process of getting a list of contacts in an app I searched for many examples and it is confusing to me .. all what I need that will help me understand is a simple code that gets contact names and numbers in an array

Comment: This is way too broad/vague. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)